# There is 250,000 dollars. Lena should get 50,000 more than Chayla. How much should Chayla get?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Chayla and lena pool their resources to buy several lottery tickets. They win 250,000! They agree that lena should get 50,000 more than chayla, because she gave most of the money. How much will chayla get?

Comment: Let Lena take 50,000 and then split the rest. It's not difficult.

Answer (score 5):

Let $x$ denote how much Chayla will get. We have:

$$x+(x+50,000)=250,000$$

hence

$$2x=200,000$$

and thus $x=100,000$.

Comment: You know,I usually get paid for help with questions like this...........

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 - Well, perhaps Lena will pay me...